# MySQL: Enumerate within Group (Banana, 1 / Banana, 2 / Banana, 3 / Apple, 1 ...)

Tags: php, mysql, enumeration

I "grouped" a query. It's a query for technical parts with versions.

Like:

```
ID , GlobalID, Name         , DateCreated
413,       17, Masterscrew  , 17.10.2014
421,       17, Masterscrew  , 28.10.2014
482,       29, Bluescrew    , 11.08.2014
519,       17, Masterscrew B, 01.12.2014
```

The goal is to do a query which has something like this as result:

```
GlobalID, Version, ID, Date
17, 1, Masterscrew, 413, 17.10.2014
17, 2, Masterscrew, 421, 28.10.2014
17, 3, Masterscrew B, 519, 01.12.2014
29, 1, Bluescrew, 482, 11.08.2014
```

The challange for is is the "Version" - column. Is there any spell I can cast to MySQL to do the magic?

Comment: No. Not really possible in any scalable way

Comment: Could you please share your query?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by one of those hairy queries with `@ID` variables in it.

```
SELECT (@ID := IF(@Prev <> GlobalID, 1, @ID + 1)) version,
       (@Prev := GlobalID) GlobalID, 
       Name, 
       ID, 
       STR_TO_DATE(DateCreated, '%d.%m.%Y') DateCreated
  FROM parts,
       ( SELECT @ID := 0, @Prev := 0 ) A
  ORDER BY GlobalID, ID
```

will do the trick. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82a36/15/0

The `@ID` variable increments every time there's a new row with the same `GlobalID` value, and resets to zero when it changes. The `@Prev` variable keeps track of the previous row's `GlobalID` value.

This line initializes those two variables.

```
 ( SELECT @ID := 0, @Prev := 0 ) Init
```

Don't change the order of the first two columns in the SELECT or the query won't work anymore.  (This is a grim MySQL hack; other RDMSs offer ranking).

Comment: I never used MySQL that way. Nice idea. ThanX.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @VERSION_NUM=0;
SET @PREV_GLOBALID=0;
SELECT
  ID,
IF(@PREV_GLOBALID!=GlobalID,@VERSION_NUM:=1, @VERSION_NUM:=@VERSION_NUM+1) as version,    
@PREV_GLOBALID:=GlobalID as GlobalID,
  name,
  DateCreated
FROM parts
ORDER BY GlobalID ASC, id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a variable for `GlobalID` say `@GlobalID` in order to compare if there is a change of GlobalID and then reset the counter to 1 otherwise add 1, like:

```
 @Num := if(@GlobalID<>GlobalID,1,ifnull(@Num,0)+1) as Num
,@GlobalID := GlobalID
```

Then make it as a complete subquery that you could use later on like:

```
SELECT ID, GlobalID, Name, DateCreated as `Date`, 
  @Num := if(@GlobalID<>GlobalID,1,ifnull(@Num,0)+1) as Num
 ,@GlobalID := GlobalID
FROM tbl, (SELECT @Num:=0) A
ORDER BY GlobalID
```

Use [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function to concatenate strings and numbers and then use also the subquery that you have earlier, so full query now would look like this:

```
 SELECT GlobalID, CONCAT(Num,', ',Name) as Version
  ,ID, `Date`
 FROM (
   SELECT ID, GlobalID, Name, DateCreated as `Date`, 
   @Num := if(@GlobalID<>GlobalID,1,ifnull(@Num,0)+1) as Num
   ,@GlobalID := GlobalID
   FROM tbl, (SELECT @Num:=0) A
 ORDER BY GlobalID ) t
```

Check my <kbd>[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55125/1)</kbd>